# The virtual device in the Android Studio emulator closes if i hold down the left mouse button on the screen to scroll

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, virtual-device-manager

I use Android Studio for my Android projects. Everything has been updated to a stable version of the AMD processor, the RAM volume in the laptop is 16 GB. There is enough memory in the disk. However, if I run an app in the emulator, and I scroll a view with the left mouse button, then the virtual device suddenly disappears. If I try to delete the virtual device from the device list or cold boot it, then I get a message saying that the device is already running. When the virtual device disappears, the screen looks like this:

[image: Log]
[image: Device]

Any help in is matter is welcome.